# after spy on thread object, thread.start(), thread.join() don't work。

Tags: mockito, spy

I can't find any documentation specifically mentions spy on thread object using mockito. But I tested using the following code (with mockito 1.8.5):

```
@Test
public void testThread() throws InterruptedException
{
    Thread threada = spy( new Thread( new Runnable()

    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println( "on thread" );
        }
    } ) );
    threada.start();
    //threada.join();
    System.out.println( "finished test" );
}
```

The "on thread" is not print out, if I put threada.join() in, I got exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-1"
finished test
```

If I remove "spy()", I got both prints ("no thread" and "finished test"), and there is no exception. Why can't I spy on Thread object?

Answer (score 1):

Please use current version of Mockito (2.X instead of 1.8.5)
I checked your code and the problem reproduces on 1.8.5, and is gone on 2.X

2.X introduced a significant change - it changed the mock maker engine from CGLIB to ByteBuddy.

Comment: Actually this bug seems to be fixed in `1.9.0` already, but I wasn't able to find the bugtracker from that time. If I remember correctly that was before the project moved to github.

Comment: @Lesiak Thanks! I tried both 1.9.0 and 2.0, both worked. It will be nice if you can point me the bug link.

Comment: Sorry, but the buggy version is ten years old now (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v1.8.5). It is no fun to grep commits/issues/mrs that old, but if you really care, you can make a git bisect yourself. I’m not even sure if it was a bug with a then-current Java version